# Unable to boot OS X on external HDD on 1 mac but fine on another. No entry sign

Tags: macos, startup

I've managed to reformat and install OS X Sierra on an external hard disk with an USB3.0 connection to a borrowed 2015 Macbook Air. The install was successful and the OS was able to boot and work fine.

However, my current Macbook Pro (mid-2012) is unable to boot the OS from the external hard disk. Holding down the option key shows the hard disk indicating that the Mac has recognised the disk drive connection, but when selecting the disk image to boot, the Apple logo flashes briefly before displaying a 'No Entry' sign.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Comment: No recent experience with this specifically but any install of macOS will , *not necessarily,* boot any model of Mac. There are some differences between certain models to prevent this from working. You may want to try internet recovery on your 2012 with that HD attached and install to that external drive. It should keep your settings and data but update it for your specific hardware.